# Changing colors on Orange Scatterplot widget?

Tags: data-mining, orange

This is probably has an obvious solution, but I cannot seem to figure it out.

I have this scatterplot below:

[image]

I know that there is a drop down menu on the left that allows you to decide how to color the data. However, I cannot seem to find a way to change which color the data points appear as. As you can see from the image above, the colors are not exactly the best for visually displaying the this data.

Answer (score 1):

I just realised I'd missed the 'colour' widget. By connecting the data table to the 'colour' widget, I could set what colour I wanted different data sets to be. Then I could attach the colour widget to my scatter plot, and BAM, the colours I wanted. I needed to make sure the scatter plot widget was connected to both the colour widget and the data table. There may be a more streamlined way to do it, but that worked.

(Posting my own answer rather than deleting, in case anyone else has similar issues).